# Closed Game effect for White

Tags: opening, analysis

As my friend said a moment ago, the Closed Game type is bad practice for White because it brings White often to draw rather than win.

If I want to get a better chance of winning, I should choose Open Game but be careful about counterattack.  However, there seem to be openings which are categorized in the middle [between Open game and Closed game].

I am annoyed a bit. But when I checked with Shredder, it seems rather true.

Is it true??

Comment: A `Closed Game` can mean two things.  Either positions with few open lines OR games that start with the opening moves 1.d4 d5.  Which do you mean?

Comment: What did Shredder say?

Comment: Sorry for late to comment. I have been take a rest. ^^, I check Shredder when I put some opening which classified `Close Game` [1. d4 d5], it will show more percentage to draw than the `Open Game`. But I accept [more likely to agree] to the condition from @Andrew Ng, that `Close Game` or `Open Game` will be achieved with transposition. So, just not always lead with first move at `1.d4 d5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed games (1.d4) and open games (1.e4) perform equally well at high levels.

It is usually recommended that less experienced players (say, under 2000 FIDE) play open games to learn, since tactics show up more often in them, and tactics is the most important aspect of the game to become fluent in.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily generalize 1. e4 or 1. d4 to lead to open and closed games, respectively. It depends more so on the individual opening than the first move.

Comment: Yes, but standard nomenclature is to refer to 1.e4 e5 as "open games", 1.e4 <other> as "semi-open games", 1.d4 d5 as "closed games", and 1.d4 <other> as "semi-closed games". It wasn't clear to me whether the OP was referring to the first couple of moves or the pawn structures that come up (which of course are correlated).

Comment: It's funny how `1.e4 e5` often leads to Ruy Lopez which usually results in very closed games.

Comment: I'd like to make point that chance win or lose is more about tactics (I am agree with [@dfan](http://chess.stackexchange.com/users/291/dfan)), not the Opening which classified `Open Game` or `Close game` since both of them can transpose to each other. ^^

Comment: 1.d4 can be used to learn tactics.

Answer (score 1):

Openings are generally categorized as Open (double K pawn), Semi-Open (1.e4 followed by a Black move other than 1..., e5, such as Sicilian (1..., c5) or Caro-Kann (1..., c6) or French Defenses (1...., e6) or Closed (Double Q pawn). I wouldn't necessarily say that these bring about a draw more often.  If you are adept at them, you can strangle you opponent slowly rather than dispatching him quickly.  The result is the same.

The double "e" pawn openings are called open since the pieces come into contact with each other sooner and tactics abound.  Conversely, in the closed openings early positional maneuvering takes precedence and tactics are delayed.  The semi-open games lead to unbalanced positions with both sides having chances.  These will be fighting games as a result.  As the other respondent has indicated, it's normally suggested that you start out with open games to gain tactical experience.  When you say being careful of counterattack, I assume that that's what you're referring to, and it's always a good idea to examine those for both sides.  Tactics are not absent from closed games, but the opportunities for same usually take longer to arise.  You'll still need to be adept in them regardless of the type of opening though.

I'd suggest that you look at an opening manual to get a better idea of the different types of opening.  I don't advocate memorizing long lines of play though. Just try to get a basic understanding of each.